# ValueError: cannot insert Date, already exists

Tags: python, pandas, count

I try to import a excel file get all dates from a column with dates and count how many events i have  every year on all days of year from 2012 till now.
And i have this error: ValueError(f"cannot insert {column}, already exists")
ValueError: cannot insert Date, already exists

```
import pandas as pd

file_path = r'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\yyy.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(file_path)
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['AVVIATO'])
data['Year'] = data['Date'].dt.year
data['DayOfYear'] = data['Date'].dt.dayofyear
df = data.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='D'), pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='Y')]).size().reset_index(name='counts')
df['CumulativeSum'] = df.groupby('Date')['counts'].cumsum()
df['YearCount'] = df.groupby('Year').cumcount() + 1
export_path = r'C:\Users\adrcl\Desktop\output.xlsx'
df.to_excel(export_path, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error line is suggesting that you might have a potential problem in on of these lines of code

- data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['AVVIATO'])
- data['Year'] = data['Date'].dt.year
- data['DayOfYear'] = data['Date'].dt.dayofyear

Therefore, the easy solution I can suggest is to read the excel file into

> data

variable, and then creating some variable such as

> filteredData = pd.DataFrame()

and adding all your updated fields to this one. ex: "filteredData['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['AVVIATO']), etc. whatever you want to write here"

Answer (score 0):

You can't reset index and create two columns with the same name `'Date'`. You have to rename index axis first:

```
df = (data.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='D'), pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='Y')])
          .size().rename_axis(['Date_D', 'Date_Y'])  # <- HERE
          .reset_index(name='counts'))
```

Output will be something like this:

```
>>> df
      Date_D     Date_Y  counts
0 2023-01-01 2023-12-31      24
1 2023-01-02 2023-12-31      24
2 2023-01-03 2023-12-31       1
```